# Increase line separation in matplotlib annotation text

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
fig.text(0.6, 0.15,
         'Line 1\n'
         'Line 2\n'
         'Line 3')
```

In matplotlib is there a way to increase line spacing between 2 lines in the command above? I tried inserting an extra `\n` but that makes the line separation too wide.

Comment: Use parameter `linespacing=2.5` to set vertical line spacing to 2.5 times the `fontsize`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With each `.text()` statement, optional parameter `linespacing` will set the vertical line spacing equal to the multiple values of the font size.
For example,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for ea in range(5):
    fig.text(0.18 + 0.15*ea, 0.15,
             'Line 1\n'
             'Line 2\n'
             'Line 3', color='b', \
             linespacing = 1+ea)
plt.show()
```

The resulting plot is:

[image]